# Invoke NSTextField's action to be send when clicked ouside

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a NSTextField that have been edited. If I press enter then action is being called as expected.

I would like to have the same effect when I click anywhere outside of NSTextField. Resigning First Responder could be the key, but that happens only when some elements are clicked/selected/focused (e.g. another NSTextField or NSTableView) and doesn't happen with others (e.g. NSButton or NSSlider).

NSTextField focus can be unset using `[[self window] makeFirstResponder:nil]` but that would be too ugly to call this line in every object's action.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to delve into the Cocoa Event Handling Guide.
Take a good look at NSResponder. 
Many objects inherit from NSResponder, including NSWindow and NSApplication. 
Taking a guess at what you are trying to accomplish, committing an edit when the view is not in focus, you may want to also include observing notifications when the app will terminate, go into the background, etc...